# how can I use single SQL transaction for multiple methods?

Tags: c#, sql, transactions

I have a code to add a new client in my application . 
say I have a save_button method in which I have few methods that will validate the entered details, then a method to create a database for the client if validation is true and then some methods that will run some saved procs.
 all these are in a sequence. Now lets say my validation is done and the clone DB is created.. noe when executing the next method my programse breaks.. 
how can I use a Single transaction that begins on my save_button and rolls back all the updated i have done to the DB is the program breaks in between. 
since when creation a database is a transaction in itself. when i try to use the initially created transaction while creating the DB it throws an exception

-------{"CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.\r\nCREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction."}----------

Comment: Which flavour of SQL is this? Does it enable nested transactions?

Comment: @AndyG im not sure if it supports the same.. as far as i know it does not . can you give an example of the sql that supports nested transaction.

Comment: Per the error message -- you cannot create a database within a transaction. It's not clear what your question is, here -- if you want to know how to do it anyway, the simple answer is "you can't". You can create objects within the database in a transaction, but the DB itself must be created outside one. There is little value in creating a database transactionally anyway, since the rollback on failure is trivial -- drop the database.

Comment: You haven't confirmed the flavour of SQL; MySQL? SQL Server..? Once known, you could discover if it supports nested transactions. However, reading a little about them, they aren't quite what they seem; in that a rollback rolls back the entire sequence. However, it may be possible to use them to overcome the specific error, because the CREATE DATABASE statement could be isolated as a non-multi-statement transaction.

Comment: This error message belongs to SQL Server, specifically, which has no real support for nested transactions (it just fakes them, rather unconvincingly) -- but nesting is neither here nor there, since it does not support `CREATE DATABASE` inside a transaction *period*. `BEGIN TRANSACTION; CREATE DATABASE Foo; ROLLBACK` is the shortest reproduction. (I'm pretty sure the whole "multi-statement" thing is a red herring -- I would be highly if pleasantly surprised if someone showed me *any* way to `ROLLBACK` creation of a database.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I believe you, personally ;). I was basing my comments on the fake news within the error message text, specifically the "multi-statement" part.